# Python code always returns False, even if function is 'return True'

Tags: python, return, spyder, return-value

Using Spyder IDE with Python, I have a function that always returns False, even if the function is literally 'return True'

I'm doing an online Python course and had to write code to see if all the letters in a word were also in a list of letters. The below code was accepted by the code checker. However, in my IDE (Spyder) the output was always False no matter the values for secretWord and lettersGuessed. I even set the function to just be 'return True' and the output was still False. Why could that be? Some issue with the IDE?

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    counter = 0
    for char in secretWord:
        if char in lettersGuessed:
            counter += 1
    if counter == len(secretWord):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Can you show us the function that is `literally return True` and how you call it?

Comment: It's likely OP wrote the initial code, executed it once, tested it in the IPython Console, made the adjustments so that the function would `return True` and tested it in the console again without executing (i.e. applying the new function definition).

Answer (score 1):

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
for char in secretWord:
    if char not in lettersGuessed:
        return False
```

return True

you can use this simple approach, if char in not present in lettersGuessed, you can directly return false. There is not point in counting size.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has no issue as you show and it does what it is supposed to do.

I tried in VSCODE:

```
def isWordGuessed(secretWord, lettersGuessed):
    counter = 0
    for char in secretWord:
        if char in lettersGuessed:
            counter += 1
    if counter == len(secretWord):
        return True
    else:
        return False


TEST1=isWordGuessed('SECRET','TRCS')
print(TEST1)
print(isWordGuessed('SECRET','TRCS'))
if isWordGuessed('SECRET','TRCS'):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)

TEST2=isWordGuessed('SECRET','TRCSE')
print(TEST2)
print(isWordGuessed('SECRET','TRCSE'))
if isWordGuessed('SECRET','TRCSE'):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

RESULT

```
False
False
False
True
True
True
```

You may want to use the debugger in Spyder so you can set some breakpoints and check the live execution in order to find out what is happening.

https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/panes/debugging.html